# bootstrap with icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add icons to this menu using bootstrap.

icon if list below is not expanded.
icon is list below is expanded.

Please view this link for working example:

JS is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html http://getbootstrap.com/components/

For the toggle, the glypicon will be toggled alongside with the content.

```
$('.tree-toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).children(".glyphicon").toggle();
    $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});
$(function(){
    $(".glyphicon-minus").toggle();  
    $('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
})
```

Comment: What if we wanted to use one span for the icon and remove/add the class?

Comment: Oops, for some reason the plunk got messed up earlier. Here's the option of you want to have only 1 span. http://plnkr.co/edit/Cax4NdrxKLvrUKRVbkih?p=preview